# How do I import the User object in Scala's web framework Lift?

Tags: scala, lift

I'm following the [Lift tutorial](http://liftweb.net/docs/getting_started/mod_master.html) and it is referencing to a `User` object.  It doesn't say where it's coming from.  I also could not find it in the API.  Does anyone know what I have to import to get it?

Here's the sample code with a FK to `User` in the model:

```
object owner extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, User)
```

Comment: It's linked in my original question, here it is again more explicitly put: http://liftweb.net/docs/getting_started/mod_master.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The User object will be part of your source. Assuming that you've done the com.liftworkshop project, it will be in todo/src/main/scala/com/liftworkshop/model/User.scala and can be imported from "com.liftworkshop.model.User".

The default User class and object are built from the MetaProtoUser and MetaMegaProtoUser traits in net.liftweb.mapper.

Comment: I noticed that User defined in the Lift book from Google book.